# Discord bot can't connect to voice or use commands as an exe file

Tags: python, discord, bots

So my program works as intended as a .py file, but once I compile it using pyinstaller into an exe I get this error. How would I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
  File "AmongUsBot.py", line 66, in on_message
    i = await found.connect(reconnect=True)
  File "site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1097, in connect
  File "site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 90, in __init__
RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states on the last line you will need to install the [PyNaCl library](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/) in order to use voice.

https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/